# Run command line script on load of a web page

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I want something like a bash script that sits and listens and then runs a script when I load a specific web page in my browser. I was wondering if something like this is possible, and if so, how do I go about it?

I'm thinking this should be possible somehow. I'm on Mac and in my `/etc/hosts` file I can specify that specific websites should be blocked, e.g. "`www.facebook.com`".

So in short. Is (and how) it possible to run a bash script when my computers browser navigates to a webpage, for example "`www.facebook.com`"?

Comment: What is your browser? You would most likely need to write a browser plugin for that.

Comment: Not possible with just a bash script I guess..

Comment: I mainly use Safari, but sometimes have to use Chrome for work.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

If you want to do some matching of the name of the site to a pre-defined site, and then say something, your script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
   site=$(osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to return URL of front document')
   if [[ $site =~ stackoverflow ]]; then
      say "Stack overflow! A quality site"
   fi
   sleep 1
done
```

**Original Answer**

You aren't very specific about what browser you are using, what the page is or what you want to do, but this script sits and watches Safari and asks it what page you are looking at and prints it in the terminal. You could obviously modify it to detect certain pages and run a script when you navigate to them.

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
   osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to return URL of front document'
   sleep 1
done
```

Put the above in a file called `monitorSafari` in your HOME directory. Then go into Terminal and type the following once to make it executable:

```
chmod +x monitorSafari
```

Then you can run it by either double-clicking it in the Finder, or by typing

```
./monitorSafari
```

in your Terminal. It prints the page you are on once every second.

Comment: Cool, this looks like a good solution. I'll try it out tomorrow. If it works I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can :

1. Start a web server (`httpd`, `lighttpd`, ...) on your Mac (or use pre-installed `httpd`)
2. Add your preferred script to the document root of the web server to run on a specific address (for example on `localhost:8080`). This script for example can be a `PHP` script that invokes your `bash` script or done the job itself. This can be done with `cgi` although.
3. Then add your preferred address (`www.facebook.com`) to your `hosts` file to redirect URL requests to `localhost:8080`
4. Or instead of modifying `hosts` file, install `dnsmasq` to manage redirection of custom requests.